# Move constructor without implementation, yet it works

Tags: c++, constructor, move-semantics

Here is some code I wrote to illustrate my question:

```cpp
struct Foo
{
    Foo() {}
    Foo( Foo && );
    Foo( const Foo & ) = delete;
};

Foo GetFoo()
{
    return Foo();
}

int main()
{
    Foo f = GetFoo();
}
```

The deleted copy constructor prevents an implicit default move constructor, so I have to explicitely declare one. But I am neither using "= default" nor providing an implementation for it, yet the whole thing compiles and links properly. If I remove the declaration, it won't compile anymore.

I find it really surprising that the linker isn't complaining about the missing move constructor. Could you please help me understand why?

Comment: It is probably elided. [Try `-fno-elide-constructors` on g++/clang++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/911900c6cccde928) and see it fail to link.

Comment: Well I just tried, and it still seems to work. http://goo.gl/P7lYjv

Comment: Weird. I get the same issue with g++4.8.2 on coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c56eede1a50e2e56 Probably godbolt does not link? Example: http://goo.gl/1BXrG8

Comment: Oh my bad, I looked for an online gcc compiler with options and thought this one was linking too, sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When initializing a variable in the form `type identifier = Function()`, the compiler affirms that a copy/move constructor is declared as usable, and then ignores it and tries to construct from the right side directly ("copy/move elision"). Then it has `Function` construct the variable directly into `main`, to skip a move/copy (this is "return value optimization").  These sort of work together and bypass any and all moves/copies, and `Function` ends up constructing `f` directly.  Since the move constructor wasn't actually used, the linker didn't look for it, and thus failed to notice the missing definition.

Comment: Yeah, I rewrote the answer now.  I'm a serious FailDuck today.